# Film with giant tentacled red aliens which show up at sunrise/sunset, their touch is deadly

Tags: story-identification, movie

The film was set on a alien planet where human soldiers fight against giant translucent red aliens with tentacles.
They show up at sunrise or sunset (I'm not sure).  They are deadly if touched.

I think this is a 2000's film.

I recall one scene where a red monster rises up behind a hill and it is huge (much higher than the hill).

Another scene features soldiers escaping in a jeep while shooting at a monster.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Also, can you draw these aliens? That would be a huge help to visualise what you're talking about.

Comment: Were the monsters good CGI, obvious low-budget CGI or practical effects? It can help too.

Comment: i think that they were medium-good CGI for the 2000's

Answer (score 6):

Apart from it being set in Mexico, not an alien planet, this reminds me very much of [*Monsters* (2010)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsters_(2010_film)).

> It has giant translucent red aliens with tentacles.
>
> They show up at sundown.
>
> They are very big.
>
> There is a scene at the beginning (and also at the end) with soldiers in a jeep attempting to escape down a road while they shoot up at one of alien lifeforms

IIRC there are also warnings about them touching you.

Comment: The one at 12'12 certainly seems like a match; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=S0hgfp_1ywM

Comment: Thanks but this is not the film i'm looking for